# Error: bash: ./: Is a directory CS50 IDE

Tags: cs50

I'm having a serious problem with CS50 IDE. Everything I did yesterday doesn't seem to be working today. I am compiling files fine, but now can't get them to run because I'm getting the error "bash: ./: Is a directory".

Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image]

And here is my folder structure

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should not be a space between ./ and the name of the file, i.e. use `./hello` and not `./ hello`. Note the space in the second command I have used.

Comment: Thank you so very much!!